# Android アプリで設定が反映されません

Tags: android, kotlin

PreferenceLibraryとkotlinを用いて設定画面を作成したのですがいったんアプリを閉じ再度開けば反映されるものの、そのまま使う場合設定が反映されません。その都度反映させるにはどうすればよいでしょう。

作っているアプリが電卓なので"="を押すたびに以下を実行させましたが駄目でした。

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
             var mode = sharedPreferences.getString("mode", "increace")
            var LEVEL = sharedPreferences.getString("level", "OFF")
```

---

#### ソースコード

**setting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="OnOff"
        android:summaryOn="オン"
        android:summaryOff="オフ"
        android:title="OnOff" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="OFF"
        android:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        android:key="level"
        android:title="List preference"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Seeting.kt**

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import com.example.sugoidentaku.R

class Setting : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        // res/xml/preferences.xml ファイルに従って設定画面を構成
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting, rootKey)
    }
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        var mode = sharedPreferences.getString("mode", "increace")
        var LEVEL = sharedPreferences.getString("level", "OFF")

 supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.setting,Setting())
            .commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

ぱっと見た限り、Android StudioのテンプレートからSetting設定をしているように見えます。

CheckBoxPreference の android:key="OnOff" に対して、

```
     var mode = sharedPreferences.getString("mode", "increace")
```

としているのでこれを

```
     var onoff = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("OnOff", false)
```

としているかを確認してください。
また、

```
    android:entries="@array/reply_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
```

ここについてもテンプレートのままのようですので、 res/values/arrays.xml　の記載を確認してください。

```
<string-array name="reply_values">
    <item>reply</item>
    <item>reply_all</item>
</string-array>
```

この様になっている場合は、levelの返却値は reply か reply_all になります。